# Unhandled Exception: Connection closed while receiving data Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, http, request

My program has a button which triggers this function:

```
onPressed: () async {
        Navigator.pushNamed(context, route);
        data = await fetchData();
        dict = jsonDecode(data);
        print(dict);
      }
```

Note that `fetchData()` function is in another file and here it is:

```
fetchData({String url = "http://10.0.2.2:5000/?query=1"}) async {
  http.Response response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
  return response.body; 
}
```

The problem is that sometimes the program successfully outputs dict and sometimes it outputs this error.

```
ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: Connection closed while receiving data
```

How can I solve this?
Also, I have another question: why is the `onPressed` function async and why do we use `await fetchData()`? Isn't it enough that we use async in the definition of `fetchData` itself? Why do we use it with its call?

Comment: Take a look at https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await to learn the basics of asynchronous programming.

Comment: idk what I missed. Maybe the return type of `fetchData`? Should it be `Future<String> fetchData`? This doesn't solve my problem anyway.